# Fails to get internal share posts of a user using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an app retrieving posts from a user. In my test on my own personal account, the application can get most of the posts using Graph API, but fails to get some internal share posts which I forwarded from other users. Share posts with external link are totally fine. But issue happens on internal share posts.

In the Graph Api Explorer, the get query 
"me/feed" gets most of the posts except posts sharing from other Facebook users' posts/videos/pictures.

Is it a bug? How can I retrieve "ALL" posts from a user?